# Sending data from Jquery to Controller 500 internal error

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Yes, I have come across this error in the past and it has to do with the csrf token, but in the past I just went to the Middleware VerifyCSRF file and included the route in the list of ignores.

However this is not working now. And I am puzzled.

The only difference I can think of is that the first time I had it on production in a server while now I am coding in cloud9 and it uses https but, since firefox gives problem when you have vulnerable code inside a https page, I deactivated that, otherwise nothing on the site would display. But that shouldn't have anything to do.

Another thing that baffles me is the fact that on loading the page, I can already see in firebug the 500 error, but this should be only activated on changing the select list, however it does happen just on page load also.

Here is the full code:

I have this in a partial since it is going to be used by 2 pages:

```
     <script>        
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    cargarProvincias();
 //   cargarCiudades();
    $('#country').change(cargarProvincias);
    $('#regions').change(cargarCiudades);

     });

        function cargarProvincias() {            
        var country = $('#country').val();  
          $regionsurl = "{{URL::route('findcountries')}}";

          $.post($regionsurl, {country:country},function(data){
                $('#regions').empty();                 
                $.each(data, function(key, value){                 
                $('#regions').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>')});
                    cargarCiudades();         
              });
          }

          function cargarCiudades(){     

          // alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
            var region = $('#regions').val();
          $url = 'http://chefvillas.com/localidades';
          $.post($url, {localidad:region},function(data){           
                $('#towns').empty();                 
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                var option = $('<option/>', {'id':key, 'text':value});
                $('#towns').append(option);
                });                 
              });               
          }   
    </script>
```

Then this is the route:

```
Route::get('/', 'SearchController@welcome');
Route::post('/', ['as' => 'findcountries','uses'=>'SearchController@findcountries' ]);
```

And this is the controller

```
 public function welcome(){
      $countries = Property::distinct()->select('country')->get();
      return view('welcome', ['countries' => $countries]);
  }


  public function findCountries(){
    $pais = Input::get('country');
    print_r($pais); // but I never get here because the error blocks it before

   }
```

I have tried this too, but no change in feedback

```
public function findCountries(){

      if (Request::ajax())
{
    $pais = Input::get('country');
      var_dump($pais);
}
```

I have been so far a full day stuck with this. I have tried to change the syntax of the route, despite the fact that this is the same code that I used in the past.

UPDATE

Here the Network tab status confirms that it is a csrf error: (Token Mismatch Exception)

but I have added the URI to the list of ignores

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = ['findcountries'];
}

TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
```

UPDATE 2

I have included this in a separate file

```
// public/js/config.js
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });
});
```

And also this metatag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

However, one thing that I keep gettin Warned about all the time is little triangles in orange color saying:

```
$ is not defined; please fix or add/* global $*/
```

[image]

But it is not just about jquery (because it is installed and it works because I have a working slider) but about any line that contains an $. If it is $url it will say url is not defined.

Comment: csrf tocken error?

Comment: yes, this is the token that Laravel includes in all posts

Comment: use `Request.ajax` in controller action to check ajax call wrap this in if condition

Comment: I have added it as indicated and I get no change in the feedback, It continues saying Internal Server Error 500

Comment: show me your network tab status

Comment: thank you for helping. I have added it above

Comment: It is strange because it says the error is in line 67 of VerifyCsrfToken.php but that file only has 15 lines

Comment: The Middleware sits between the Routes and the Controller. It is this middleware that is complaining about the Token. That is why there is a file to exclude "conflictive" route names, but it is not working this time, it is as if the route name were not the one in question, but of course it is.

Comment: try this when you calling ajax `$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }`

Answer (score 0):

When your first ajax call succeeds, your second post request: `cargarCiudades()` is getting called and NOR you have included this second post route in `$except` array in your csrf middleware NEITHER you have included the `csrt_token` in the request's parameters.

I think the `TokenMismatchException` is thrown when your second request is called.

Comment: Hi thanks. I removed the second ajax calls and no change. Besides, the var_dump at the controller would have stopped the continuation before the second function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Write the route **URI** instead of the route **NAME**.

```
protected $except = ['/'];
```